# Proposal: Begone with [difference]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-cleaning

**Proposal three:** Blacklist or at least remove [difference](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/difference).

**Does [difference](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/difference) make a difference?**

1. It fits the perfect description of a [meta tag](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/). It describes the type of the question, not its content. It can't be the only tag on a question.
2. The tag has a vague name in itself. One of the prerequisites of a [good] tag is having a name as clear as possible, **without taking a good tag wiki into account**. No matter how well this tag's wiki has been written, its name is vague and that's a very grave disadvantage.
3. This tag is useless. It doesn't categorize anything. No one uses it for searching. It's just a means of adding more tags to a question.
4. Even if you had some counterarguments for what I said above, you can't deny the fact that, with respect to the mere existence of tags like [word-choice](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-choice), [transatlantic-differences](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transatlantic-differences), [word-difference](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-difference), [synonyms](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/synonyms) and the "vs" tags, this tag is as redundant as it gets.

So, what do you guys say we blacklist or at least burninate it?

---

Related: **[Is the tag "word-difference" useful since we already have the tag "difference"?](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1230/is-the-tag-word-difference-useful-since-we-already-have-the-tag-difference)**

Comment: The title should be: "Does this tag make a [difference]?"

Comment: @DJMc I already made a pun in the post. I wanted the title to be coherent with the other recent proposals I made.

Answer (score 1):

To me, it seems a too broad tag to be useful in any way; knowing that the question is about a not well defined difference is not much helpful to categorize the question, nor for the users who answer it.
 In most of the cases, the question is really about something else more specific, such as the meaning of a word/phrase, or the choice between two words, for which there is already a tag.

Keep in mind that blacklisting a tag is not possible until the tag is used from questions. To do so, the questions should be first edited to remove the tag, which also means replacing it with the more appropriate tag. After that, the tag can eventually be blacklisted. This is done very rarely, though; I have this done in very few cases.

Comment: This is just to the point. When I feel like it, I might gather a bunch of people and <strike> go hunt copy-editor badges </strike> do some tweaks to the tag system. There are many bad tags on the line to be removed, but it seems many people are busy these days.